# Creating zoom change event handler using ArcGIS JS API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, zoom, event-listener

I want to change from a cached Basemap to a dynamic Basemap when the zoom is past a certain level. All Basemaps stored inside view's baseMapLayout (assume currently there's only 2). view is an ArcGIS View object.

"mouse-wheel" seems to be a MapView only event.

My current code:

```js
view.onEvent("mouse-wheel", ()=>{
    if(view.getZoom() > 18) view.changeBasemap("A")
    else view.changeBasemap("B")
})
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, your current code works on `mouse-wheel` event, but you want it to work on zoom change event?

Comment: No. mouse-wheel doesn't seem to be a valid event for View. So the event isn't triggered. I am trying to use mouse-wheel for zoom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reactiveUtils` (see https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-core-reactiveUtils.html and https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/programming-patterns/#watching-for-property-changes) to watch for `view.zoom` property change. Watch for `view.stationary` can be added to skip zoom changes during animation.

In your case code could look something like this:

```
var currZoom = null;

const handle = reactiveUtils.watch(
  () => [view.stationary, view.zoom],
  ([stationary, zoom]) => {
    if(stationary && (zoom != currZoom)){
      currZoom = zoom;
      if (zoom > 18)
        view.changeBasemap("A");
      else
        view.changeBasemap("B");
    }
   }
);
```

Comment: That was very useful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for that info! Done. I am new to stack exchange.